# Using Math::Polygon to determine if point is inside a polygon. Not working

Tags: perl, polygon, cpan

I am trying to determine if a certain point is inside of a polygon.  Trying to use Math::Polygon.  I have the boundary of the polygon in a mySQL table as one record per point for the polygon:
example:
1,38.33208,-75.51919
 
2,38.33286,-75.52265
etc.
38,38.33208,-75.51919

No matter what I do, the routine will not show the point inside the polygon despite the fact that the point would be truly inside the polygon.

Here's the relevant code

```perl
use Math::Polygon;

my @poly = ();
$sqlc = "SELECT segment,lat,lon FROM boundary WHERE xxxxxxx ";
my $stcc = $dbh->prepare(qq{$sqlc});
$stcc->execute();
while(($seg,$slat,$slon) = $stcc->fetchrow_array())
{
    $poly[$seg] = ([$slat,$slon]);
}
my $bound = Math::Polygon->new(points => @poly);
my @this_loc = ([$lat2,$lon2]);

if($bound->contains( $this_loc ))
{
    # never reaches this point. 
}
```

No matter what, I can't get the ->contains() routine to ever return true.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `use strict; use warnings;`? If not, you should.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be (at least) two errors:

```
my $bound = Math::Polygon->new(points => @poly);
```

the constructor takes a reference to an array, not an array. So it should be:

```
my $bound = Math::Polygon->new(points => \@poly);
```

Second, `$bound->contains( )` takes a reference to a point array, so it should be:

```
if($bound->contains( \@this_loc )) { ... }
```

Comment: Changing to 
`my $bound = Math::Polygon->new(points => \@poly);`
...appears to have worked.  Thanks

If I add the backslash to @this_loc, I get:
Use of uninitialized value $y in numeric eq (==) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Math/Polygon/Calc.pm line 286.
Use of uninitialized value $y in numeric le (<=) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Math/Polygon/Calc.pm line 294.
plus others for gt (>) and gt(>) also at line 294.

Comment: @MichelleBradley Great! Have you defined `$lat2` and `$lon2`?

Comment: Yes, those were defined elsewhere.  This was just the relevant snippet of code.

Comment: Can you check again the `$lon2` is defined? You could also send me the code you are working on, and I will have a look at it (my email is in my profile).